# Is it possible to use both gridview1_rowcommand and gridview1_rowdeleting together?

Tags: c#

I have a gridview which is like

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name" SortExpression="FileName">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FileName") %>' CommandName='<%#Eval("FileName") %>'>
     </asp:LinkButton>

   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" >
  <ControlStyle ForeColor="Red" />
</asp:CommandField>
```

Rowcommand part works well. When I click on delete, the control goes to `gridview1_rowcommand` instead of `gridview1_rowdeleting` and gives error.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's be helpful if you showed your two event handlers.

It sounds like you have a row_command method setup to use from the linkbutton. The issue is that a delete is still a row command, and that event is firing first (and your code probably expects a linkbutton command). So you would need to not do anything with that command and then the row_deleting with fire.

```
protected void gridview1_rowcommand(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) {
   if(e.CommandName.ToLower() != "delete") {
      // do whatever you want to with linkbutton events
   }
}

protected void gridview1_rowdeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) {
   // this will fire second, right before the record deletes
}
```

Comment: can u tell me tht how can i go to next page? I have checked allow paging. But whenever i click on numbers the same error occurs.

Comment: set a debugger on the line "if(e.CommandName.ToLower() != "delete")) {". Use quick watch or hover over the CommandName to find out the commandName. Then make sure you ignore it too, just like "delete"